# Entity framework one to many relationship in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, listview, entity-relationship

I have 4 tables being used.

> 1. Users :: ID(PK), Name, Email.
> 2. UserMessage :: ID(PK), Subject, Body, Sentdate.
> 3. UsersFromMessage :: ID(PK), FromUSerID(FK (PK => (Users))), MessageTableID(FK (PK => (UserMessage))) and some extra colms.
> 4. UsersToMessage :: ID(PK), FromUSerID(FK (PK => (Users))), MessageTableID(FK (PK => (UserMessage))) and some extra colms.

I have my database design shared above.

Consider a mail application without smtp as a example.

Assume my user table having 3 users.
U1,U2 & U3.

U1 sends a message to U2 and U3.
So one entry goes to UserMessage table 2 entries goes to UsersToMessage table and one entry goes to UsersFromMessage table.

Now i want to display all messages sent from U1 so i use the following query,

Assume userid  as 1 for time being.

```
ForumEntities objEntities = new ForumEntities();
 List<UsersFromMessage> lstUsers = objEntities.UsersFromMessages.Where(x => x.FromUserID == 1).Tolist();
```

I get data for User, UsersFromMessage but i dont get any info about UserToMessage as it has no direct relationship with UsersFromMessage table.

I am able to display Message sent from U1 but now i want to display names of all the users to whom the message was sent by U1 and bind to Listview.

Answer (score 0):

Your message class should look like the following:

```
public class Message
{
    ...
    public virtual User From { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<UsersToMessage> To { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can user the following to get your list of To users:

```
var msg = objEntities.Message.Where(m => m.From.ID == "U1").First();
var tousers = msg.To;
```

Comment: Do you mean to say i should create a custom class for this and then bind that class as a datasource.

Comment: can`t i get the values from the entity framework model itself..or can you suggest any changes into my entity framework model.